# Wordpress Google Maps plugin

Tags: php, json, wordpress, google-maps

I have a plugin which asks the user for their address details and stores them as various strings. I need to convert this into a Google Map. The code I have so far, which isn't working is:

```
<?php

if( $addresslineone ) {
$addresslineone = preg_replace('/\s+/', '+', $addresslineone);
}
if( $addresslinetwo ) {
$addresslinetwo = preg_replace('/\s+/', '+', $addresslinetwo);
}
if( $city ) {
$city = preg_replace('/\s+/', '+', $city);
}
if( $county ) {
$county = preg_replace('/\s+/', '+', $county);
}
if( $pcode ) {
$pcode = preg_replace('/\s+/', '+', $pcode);
}

$request = file_get_contents("http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=" . $addresslineone . "+" . $addresslinetwo . "+" . $city . "+" . $county . "+" . $pcode . "&sensor=false");
$json = json_decode($request, true);

$map_id = uniqid( 'map_' ); // generate a unique ID

<div id="<?php echo esc_attr( $map_id ); ?>" style="height: 300px; width: 300px;"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var map_<?php echo $map_id; ?>;
        function run_map_<?php echo $map_id ; ?>(){
            var location = new google.maps.LatLng("<?php echo $json['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lat']; ?>", "<?php echo $json['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lng']; ?>");
            var map_options = {
                zoom: 15,
                center: location,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            }
            map_<?php echo $map_id ; ?> = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("<?php echo $map_id ; ?>"), map_options);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: location,
            map: map_<?php echo $map_id ; ?>
            });
        }
        run_map_<?php echo $map_id ; ?>();
    </script>


?>
```

Any ideas what I have done wrong?

Comment: have you verified that all the variables (including `$json` are assigned a value ? ) also, can you post the real output of the Javascript and not only source code ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply - $json returns the correct values, lng/lat, I tested by echoing the string. The current script as-is does not return any value..

Comment: Like I said before - can you please paste the output of the script from the browser ?

Comment: @ObmerkKronen - not entirely sure what you mean? It currently does not output anything..

Comment: the div that has the map as ID and whatever is inside between the tag `<script type="text/javascript">` and `</script>`